# Problems with list manipulation in Swift after iOS update 14.4.2

Tags: ios, swift

For some years, I use this simple code to read and manipulate a list in Swift:

```
if (Helper.hasSubscription()) {
                    
                    self.allVisitedTrackHandles = Database.getAllCompletedTrackHandles(withDeleted: false, userid: self.userid)
                    
                    if (self.allVisitedTrackHandles.count > 0) {
                        
                        var counter = 0
                        
                        for th: TrackHandle in self.allTrackHandles {
                            
                            if self.allVisitedTrackHandles.contains(where: { $0.trackid == th.trackid }) {
                                
                                for thv: TrackHandle in self.allVisitedTrackHandles {
                                    
                                    if thv.trackid == th.trackid {
                                        
                                        self.allTrackHandles[counter].date_in_milliseconds = thv.date_in_milliseconds
                                        
                                        break
                                    }
                                    
                                }
                                
                                self.allTrackHandles[counter].visited = 1
                                
                            }
                            
                            
                            counter += 1
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
```

After updating my iOS device to iOS 14.4.2, app is crashing on this line:

```
for th: TrackHandle in self.allTrackHandles
```

Only feedback Xcode gives me is this: Thread 79: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x12f100010)

Comment: `th: TrackHandle` are you sure that's the right syntax? I've never heard of type casting that way

Comment: It's not type casting, it's just (unnecessarily) declaring the type of `th`; Swift can infer the type of `th` but it doesn't hurt to state it explicitly.

Comment: Since you actually want the indices of your `allTrackHandles` why don't you just use a `for counter in 0..<allTrackHandles.count {` instead. Then you can get rid of the manual increment of the counter. The `if ... contains ...` is kind of pointless too. You iterate over (potentially) all `allVisitiedTrackHandles` only to repeat the same iteration if you do find a match

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why that line would suddenly start crashing; There is nothing in the code shown that would cause the crash.  Are you updating the array somewhere else?  Is this, perhaps, a threading issue?

You can refactor this code to make it simpler, clearer and more efficient.  This may help;

```
if Helper.hasSubscription() {
    self.allVisitedTrackHandles = Database.getAllCompletedTrackHandles(withDeleted: false, userid: self.userid)
    if !self.allVisitedTrackHandles.isEmpty {
    
        for index in 0..<self.allTrackHandles.count {
            if let visited = self.allVisitedTrackHandles.first { $0.track id == self.allTrackHandles[index].track id } {
                self.allTrackHandles[index].date_in_milliseconds = visited.date_in_milliseconds
            }
            self.allTrackHandles[index].visited = 1                        
        }
    }    
}
```